# How do I structure my project in a Views folder

Tags: php, html, css

I want to structure my project in the following way:
[image: Project structure]

I want to put all my HTML files in a folder called `views`.
`partials` hold the files `head.html`, `footer.html` and `header.html`. Those are three short HTML snippets that gets included in my Views; So that when I change something in the header, I won't have to change it in individually in each view. But just once in the partial.

`media` holds my images. `css` and `js` respectively my styling and Javascript.

This is the structure I want to have, but I encounter the following problems:

1. How to avoid having http://example.com/views/index.php? I just want http://example.com/index.php.

I tried this by using htaccess MOD_REWRITE; but this also messed up my includes.

2. How do I include my CSS and Javascript from the head partial?

So, I have a head-partial that looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/general.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/general.js" defer></script>
```

This gets put into all views by using PHP's `file_get_contents()`. However, I need to statically link these two files somehow. How would I do that?

3. My partials get loaded like this:

```
<?php
            echo file_get_contents("partials/head.html");
        ?>
```

Also, how would I do that statically?
I tried it by using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but this returns `/Users/myName/...` which results in my includes failing.

The ideal solution would be if I could just link everything by starting from my folder called `vereniging` like `href="/css/..."` `src="/media/...`.

Edit:
This is my current htaccess content:

```
RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]


# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is solved with the following `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(views|css|js|media|partials|php)
RewriteRule (.*) /views/$1
```

The second and third problem is solved the following way:

```
<base href="http://example.com/" target="_self">
```

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use some frameworks such as laravel or Codeigniter which completes your goals.

1. For removing views from your url, edit your .htaccess as follows

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^views(/.*|)$ $1 [L]
2. To add you css you need to exit from the index directory then access those folders like below.

> href="../css/general.css"

Comment: I have solved the last two issues by using the `base`-tag in HTML. Your mod_rewrite however doesn't work... I have updated my question with my current htaccess content